# What is the difference between these two following approaches?

Tags: c#, boolean

I have following code snippet.

```
bool b = false;
if (b) {}
```

but I have seen many people write something like:

```
if (true == b){}
```

They both look same to me, is there any difference here ?

Comment: yes the second one is calculating if a boolean is equal to another boolean first and applying the if statement on the result of that... of course the compiler probably removes this step first

Comment: btw, I believe that good practice is either to write if (b) or if (b != false) - in case of bool type, if (b == true) is surely ok as well, but just from historical reasons (in C, when true was defined usually simply as "not 0") it seems to me a little bit "cleaner"... but again, in C#, if (b == true) is surely ok if b is guaranteed that it's bool

Comment: it's all about readability and the style of the programmer

Answer (score 4):

```
bool b;
if (b) {}
```

You can't use this because C# compiler doesn't allow to use unassigned local variables.

On the other hand, there is no difference between

```
bool b = true;
if (b) {}
```

and

```
bool b = true;
if (true == b){}
```

They generate same [MSIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code as well. But in my opinion, equality checking in second example is unnecessary. That's why `if(b)` seems cleaner than `if(true == b)`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a difference. (well, apart from the number of typed letters i suppose).

```
bool b = true; //ensure you initialise it though!! (if it was **C** you wouldn't think not to!)
```

So;

```
if(b)
{
 //doSomthing...
}
```

means

```
if(true)
{
 //doSomething...
}
```

**However,**

if b was assigned to false, then the if statement would be skipped; like so:

```
bool b = false;
if(b)
{
//this won't be executed since b is false
}
```

---

As for your question, though, with you initialising b at the beginning, then yes, they would be the same

Comment: Yes there is a difference as explained in my comment, and no `if(b)` doesn't mean that, it means "if b is true"

Comment: if b is assigned true, then yes, it does mean if(true) does it not?

Comment: No it doesn't because b can be reassigned to false which would skip the if statement, `if(true)` will always enter the statement.

Comment: and hence, if b was assigned to false, then yes, it would skip... but I see what you mean - will clarify now

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
if (true == b){}
```

is quite inelegant. 
Following that style in place of

```
if (a == b){}
```

you should put

```
if ((a == b) == true){}
```

and so on....

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement needs a boolean expression (the condition) to be `true` in order to execute the instructions inside its block. If you compare a boolean value to another boolean value you still get a boolean result, but, unless you are comparing two boolean variables with an unknown value, you may be writting a piece of useless code. 
To explain myself better:

```js
bool a, b;

// some computation

if(a == b)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

makes sense, while

```js
bool a;

// some computation

if(a == true)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

contains some useless code (in my opinion, it even loses some readability) because it is the equivalent of:

```js
bool a;

// some computation

if(a)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code:

```
bool b = true;
if (b) 
    Console.WriteLine("b-ok");
if (b==true)
    Console.WriteLine("b-true");
```

if we check the IL-CODE for the the first *if*

```
IL_000b:  ldloc.0
IL_000c:  ldc.i4.0
IL_000d:  ceq
IL_000f:  stloc.1
IL_0010:  ldloc.1            
IL_0011:  brtrue.s   IL_001e 
IL_0013:  ldstr      "b-ok"   
IL_0018:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)  
IL_001d:  nop
```

and for the second *if*

```
IL_001e:  ldloc.0
IL_001f:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0020:  ceq
IL_0022:  stloc.1
IL_0023:  ldloc.1
IL_0024:  brtrue.s   IL_0031
IL_0026:  ldstr      "b-true"
IL_002b:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_0031:  ....
```

We can clearly see that C# compiler produces the same IL code for both statements. Thus both approaches are totally same.